# How to convert UDate from one timezone to another using ICU

Tags: c++, icu

After spending some significant amount of time, I could not figure out how to convert UDate from one timezone to another. Here is the problem I am trying to solve :

I have a timestamp which is number of milliseconds since epoch. This is a timestamp in UTC. I want to convert this timestamp to a timestamp at some local time zone (e.g. US/Eastern). I want to extract number of days since epoch and number of milliseconds since from converted timestamp. I want to use icu library to do this.

I tried to create a UDate from number of milliseconds since epoch in UTC. I can create a timezone instance for the given timezone.

```
TimeZone *tz = TimeZone::createTimeZone("US/Eastern");
```

How do I convert UDate from UTC to the given timezone and extract the answers I want? Could it be done using icu? 
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I want … number of days since epoch and number of milliseconds since from converted timestamp.

I think these will be the same regardless of time zone, won't they?

Or can you give an example of the result you would like to see (before vs. after)

Comment: I just posted something that demonstrates the problem experienced by the original poster, please help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57560291/display-icu-udate-formatted-for-different-timezones

Comment: but to @ToyElephant ’s original question:  I'm still not sure what the question is